# iOS15 WkWebview using `Video` causes crashes - `WebAVPlayerController valueForUndefinedKey - playingOnMatchPointDevice `

Tags: ios, object

iOS15 Webview's HTML using Video tag, the following crash occurs, does anyone know what is the reason for this?

"[<WebAVPlayerController 0x282f41420> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key playingOnMatchPointDevice."

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69792214/ios15-webview-using-video-causes-crashes-webavplayercontroller-valueforunde

Comment: It has been solved, there is a [IM open source SDK-MobileimSDK4i] in the project, it will be good after deleting, the subsequent specific block of the problem is unknown!

Answer (score 1):

It has been solved, there is a [IM open source SDK-MobileimSDK4i] in the project, it will be good after deleting, the subsequent specific block of the problem is unknown!